# return table in postgresql two case

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am migrating stored procedure from SQL SERVER to POSTGRESQL. I should return table. But, I have following problem:

```
IF ROWSTATE = 'L' THEN
      return TABLE A;
ELSIF ROWSTATE = 'C' THEN
      return TABLE B;
END IF
```

How to do it, using function in POSTGRESQL?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stored procedures do not return anything in PostgreSQL. You might wanna take a look at functions.

Comment: Is ROWSTATE a variable or a function parameter ?

Comment: function input parametr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a function that `RETURNS TABLE` with the columns expected from tables `a` and `b`, e.g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(rowstate text)
RETURNS TABLE (ret_col1 text, ret_col2 text) AS $$ 
BEGIN
  IF $1='L' THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT cola1, cola2 FROM a;
  ELSEIF $1='C' THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT colb1, colb2 FROM b;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c9e9e020c8296bb95efea02a9831890d)

Comment: Thank you your answer, but two table has different column number and column type not the same. In this situation, what will should do?

Comment: @DilyorToshboltayev Well, in this case there is no way to return a table.

Comment: @DilyorToshboltayev perhaps you might wanna return the table records as a `json` string? doing so you are able to return different columns and types

Comment: [link][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZLa9.png

Comment: @DilyorToshboltayev nice! Keep in mind: By casting the columns you might be able to transform an int into text, but not necessarily the other way around ;) If you can control that in the function's logic, I see no problem :)

Comment: Since your tables have *different column number and column type* you **cannot** have a single function returning table. You could have a single function that returns a [reference cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-DECLARATIONS). Another possibility: have the calling routine decide which of 2 routines to invoke.  While returning values using a Function is the preferred method Procedures can have IN/INOUT arguments.